# The kernel dies with jax.random.PGRNKey

Tags: python, jax

[Kernel dies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVLrC.png)

The kernel dies with jax.random.PGRNKey.
python version is 3.10.10.
jax version is 0.4.9. jaxlib version is 0.4.9.
It was run on M2 MacBook using Jupyter lab.
What should I do to make it work?

I upgraded the version of packages, and it didn't work.
I have no idea on why it keep crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the jaxlib 0.4.9 release is broken on Mac ARM (see [JAX Issue #15951](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/15951)). For now I'd recommend installing jax/jaxlib version 0.4.8 to fix the issue.

Update: jax & jaxlib 0.4.10 have been released, and should fix this issue.

Comment: Downgrading it solved the problem! Thank you.